# How to make colored indicator

Tags: android, widget

I want to make an indicator for the RSSI of bluetooth signal. I know how can I get the RSSI, but what I am inquiring about is , how to make the color indicator as shown in [this link](http://cdn.appcrawlr.com/imageService/aHR0cHM6Ly9saDYuZ2dwaHQuY29tL2lFZlBTUE1WY3YyUmFKWnhVWlB0VHFsR0FQZks1Z3VnYk9lX0c1cjBfUHc5dkwxbGJTRDhURE5UUDVPSGlxX1pOZz1oNjQw%3Fw%3D340%26h%3D280)

is it a built in widget in android??

Comment: You can use custom progress bar for this

Comment: @Nithinlal would you please provide an example

Comment: check the link http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/

Comment: @Nithinlal thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom progress bar for this [Sample](http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/)